# How to check database in a service Android

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

Im developing Android for a month now and can't seem to find a solution with this.

What I want is to send a notification if there's any change in the Database, can't seem to find the answer on Google. What I want to know is: should I run asynctask on service? Or directly run the code inside the doInBackground on startcommand on MyService class? How do I achieve this?

I tried putting asynctask on service and using the code on doInBackground, but can't make it work, so if you guys know the answer, can you post a little code to guide me up? Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more Information for anyone to solve this question. What kind of Database Service are you using? Room, SQLite, Realm, ... etc. 

Also should this be a Notification the users sees or just for you app to do some work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public class AlertService extends Service {
    public AlertService() {
    }

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://localhost/ServiceAlarme.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject js=new JSONObject(response);
                        String etat=js.getString("etat");
                        if(etat.equals("1"))
                        {
                            int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345;
                            NotificationManager notif = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                            Notification n = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setContentTitle("SERVICE ALARME").setContentText("Alerte du ALARME du GAZ").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.bubble).build();
                            n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                            n.flags |=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                            long[] vibrate = { 0, 100, 200, 300 };
                            n.vibrate = vibrate;
                            notif.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,n);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("d","0");
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue rq= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    rq.add(sr);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

}
`

Comment: `protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        startService(new Intent(Inscription.this,AlertService.class));
    }`